# Localized resources in silverlight class library

Tags: silverlight, localization, resources

I have created a silverlight class library which is going to be consumed by multiple client projects. Inside the class library I have a localized dialog box showing the localized text: `You have unsaved pending changes`. This text is stored in `Messages.resx` (and the translations in `Messages.da.resx` etc.) and accessed like this:

```
Prompt.Announce(Messages.Verify, Messages.UnsavedChanges)
```

However when I add a reference to the class library dll from my silverlight client projects, the dialog box always shows up with the default language (english).

I can see that the class library build output is like this

- root

  - SilverlightClassLib.dll
  - da
  - SilverlightClassLib.resources.dll

But the client build output is missing this, so I'm guessing that the danish translations are hiding in there - but how do I include this in the consuming silverlight client projects?

UPDATE:
This is the folder structure in TFS:

- Classlib

  - Distribution

    - da
  - References
  - Source
- Client

  - References
  - Source

Comment: Does it work during VS debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a deployment problem. You need to deploy the satellite assemblies of your class library (da\SilverlightClassLib.resources.dll) in your client's binary folder (still in a "da" subfolder, if missing).

Comment: Isn't there an automated way to do this? It's unfeasible to have to copy the dlls locally when the class library is redeployed. When you include .NET dlls such as System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework, the corresponding .resources.dll is automatically deployed into the client bin folder. Is it possible to achieve this (without having to install into GAC or similar)?

Comment: How do you manage the dependency in your client projects? If using NuGet, you could include the satellite assemblies alongside the class library in the package.

Comment: Everything is stored in TFS, so I build the classlib to a source controlled "Distribution" folder, copy the dlls to a source controlled "References" folder under the client project, and add a reference to the dlls from there (I updated the question to reflect the TFS folder structure)  
So far I just copied the main classlib dll, and not the language subfolders, but even if I do that, I don't see how I could include them in the client project.

Comment: I've achieved what you are trying to do in the past using NuGet (i.e. I created NuGet packages containing not just the class library but also the accompanying satellite assemblies containing translations), but I haven't tried managing binaries manually so I can't comment much. You could try adding explicit references to the satellite assemblies in your VS project, but it's not pretty.